# How to change the POJO property name when returning JAX-RS Response?

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs

I want to use the default JAX-RS response deserializer.

Here is my POJO

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Email
{
    private String       mFrom;
    private List<String> mTo;
    private List<String> mCc;
    private List<String> mBcc;
    private String       mSubject;
    private String       mText;

public void setFrom(String from)
{
    mFrom = from;
}

@JsonProperty("from")
public String getFrom()
{
    return mFrom;
}

@JsonProperty("to")
public List<String> getTo()
{
    return mTo;
}

public void setTo(List<String> to)
{
    mTo = to;
}

@JsonProperty("carbon_copy")
public List<String> getCc()
{
    return mCc;
}

public void setCc(List<String> cc)
{
    mCc = cc;
}

@JsonProperty("blind_carbon_copy")
public List<String> getBcc()
{
    return mBcc;
}

public void setBcc(List<String> bcc)
{
    mBcc = bcc;
}
}
```

This my JAX-RS code.

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json", "application/xml", "text/xml")
public Response getEmails() {
    List<Email> emails = getEmails(); //returns list of emails
    return Response.ok(emails).build();
}
```

output

```
[{"from":"example@isp.com","to":[ ],"cC":[ ],"bCc":[ ],"subject":"my subject","text":"email from admin"}]
```

I want to change "cC" to the "carbon_copy". I want to solve this using the JAX-RS Response. How do I get JAX-RS to use the jackson annotated property name. Do I need to override something?

My current implementation i did the following.

```
public class JsonDeserializer
{
    private static ObjectMapper mMapper;
    static 
    {
        mMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static <T> T fromInputStream(InputStream is, Class t)
    {
        try
        {
            return (T) mMapper.readValue(is, t);
        }
        catch (JsonParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (JsonMappingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
 }

Response.ok(JsonDeserializer.toJson(emails)).build();
```

Is there away to do it without creating another class to handle the deserialization process.

Answer (score 1):

Mix-in can help you resolve this. You need to create an abstract class say "EmailExpanded" that has the property something like this:

```
@JsonProperty("carbon_copy")
public abstract List<String> getCc();
```

Then add that mixin:

```
emailExpandMapper = new ObjectMapper();
emailExpandMapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(
            Email.class, EmailExpanded.class);
emailExpandMapper.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationInclusion(
            Inclusion.NON_NULL);
```

Later in the code while you send the response:

```
emailExpandMapper.writeValueAsString(emails)
```

You can read more about Mixins in the web.

Comment: with this approach I would have to create an object mapper for each property I want to change. Do you know if there is another way. My current solution, I placed Jackson ObjectMapper into a static class and deserialize it that way.